# How can I delete messages older than 1 hour in Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm working on functionality to delete messages in a specific channel older than 1 hour. I have a notification system, and each time a new notification (discord message) is sent, my goal is to delete all previous ones that were sent more than an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const channelId = 'YOUR_CHANNEL_ID';
const hourInMillis = 3600000; 

let messageTimestamps = {}; 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.channel.id === channelId) {
        const now = new Date().getTime();
        messageTimestamps[message.id] = now; 
        
        // Delete old messages
        for (const [msgId, timestamp] of Object.entries(messageTimestamps)) {
            if (now - timestamp > hourInMillis) {
                const oldMessage = await message.channel.messages.fetch(msgId);
                if (oldMessage) {
                    oldMessage.delete().catch(err => console.error(err));
                    delete messageTimestamps[msgId];
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

client.login('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN');
```